# GeoTools to read featureSource from a different postgresql schema than public

Tags: java, postgresql, postgis, geotools

Working my way through GeoTools. Just trying to read features from a view in postgresql that is not in `public` schema. I have a bunch of views in a schema called `cache`

```java
store = DataStoreFinder.getDataStore(map);
// print a bunch of tables and views including the one I want
for(String s:store.getTypeNames()) 
   System.out.println(s);
```

I can see my view name in the list eg: `vw_well` without the prefix `cache`

but

```java
featureSource = store.getFeatureSource("vw_well");
```

will generate

```
WARNING: Error occured determing srid for vw_well.geom
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "public.vw_well" does not exist
```

and

```java
featureSource = store.getFeatureSource("cache.vw_well");
```

generates

`Schema 'cache.vw_well' does not exist.`

Any way to tell GeoTools to read in a different schema than `public.  I googled around I could not find an answer.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't show the code setting your [`map` of parameters](https://docs.geotools.org/stable/userguide/library/jdbc/postgis.html), but I suspect you didn't include a `schema` key so the database connection defaults to `public`. You need a line like:

```
map.put(PostgisNGDataStoreFactory.SCHEMA.key, "cache");
```

Comment: Thanks.  I did not expect it would be in the connection parameters since it implies one is limited to a single schema per connection.  But in my particular case, it solves the problem.  Thanks

Comment: You are limited to one schema per connection - allows for some security and separation of concerns